# DropDownList in ASP.net pages has OnSelectedIndexChanged fire twice

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, viewstate, autopostback

html

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOffice" runat="server" Rows="10" Width="300px" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlOffice_SelectedIndexChanged" EnableViewState="true"   />
```

Even though according to MSDN I am doing everything correctly. the SelectedIndexChanged still fires twice. Any ideas how this can fixed?

Comment: Check the designer file and make sure it isn't also listed there, and if it's VB.Net, remove the Handles clause.

Comment: that worked! make that an answer and I will accept it

Comment: @Tim, VB.NET unfortunately. I dealt with this before in c# and having the mark up as above was sufficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason: If you have a also registered the event handler in codebehind(f.e. via `Handles` clause in VB.NET or `+=` in C#) it will cause the event to be fired twice.

Then you just have to remove one of it, for example on aspx:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOffice" 
    runat="server" Rows="10" Width="300px"
    AutoPostBack="true" 
    EnableViewState="true"   />
```